# Do I need synchronise on objects which guarantee happen-before?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locking, thread-safety

I have a collection which guaranteed to be visible across threads. However that doesn't guarantee visibility of states of items which are stored in this collection(eg. if I have collection of  StringBuilder(mutable, not thread safe) then I have to synchronize on each item in collection  during write/read, right?). So, what happens when I have collection of objects which are used for guaranteeing happen-before by themselves(eg. countdownlatch). Do I need to synchronize on each item somehow when calling await/countDown? Code below roughly illustrate this dilemma:

```
public class SyncQuestion {

final List<CountDownLatch> lathces = new ArrayList<CountDownLatch>();

SyncQuestion() {
    lathces.add(new CountDownLatch(1));
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    final SyncQuestion sync = new SyncQuestion();

    final Thread sleepingThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            for (CountDownLatch latch : sync.lathces) {
                try {
                    latch.await();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        };
    };

    final Thread wakingThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            for (CountDownLatch latch : sync.lathces) {
                latch.countDown();
            }
        };
    };

    sleepingThread.start();
    wakingThread.start();
    sleepingThread.join();
    wakingThread.join();
}
```

}

Please correct me in my assumptions, if they are wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `CountDownLatch` is basically a wrapper on `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` whose state is a volatile int that is  mutated via `Unsafe.compareAndSwapInt` (which is an atomic operation).

Therefore in this specific case, as Cameron Skinner said, there is no need to synchronize because it enforces that happens-before for you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you need to manually synchronize in this case because the latches are internally thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks Cameron. Though your answer is correct I accepted one from Matt because of more detailed explanation(really helps me).